# Как сделать, чтобы первый запуск функции прошел без задержки, а потом она выполнялась с определенным интервалом?

Tags: javascript, jquery

В примере вставлены элементы маркированного списка. После того, как мы прокрутим страницу на `300рх` вниз, запустится функция, которая окрасит их в зеленый цвет.

**Вопрос:** Как сделать, чтобы первый запуск прошел сразу, а не через `6400ms`?

```js
i = 0;

function add() {

  setInterval(function() {
    $("ul li").each(function(i, el) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(el).addClass("active");
      }, 0 + (i * 800));
    })
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("ul li").removeClass("active");
    }, 5600)
  }, 6400)

}

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var top = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (i < 1 && top > 300) {
    add();
    i = 1;
  }
})
```

```css
        body {
          height: 2800px;
        }
        ul {
          display: block;
          position: fixed;
        }
        li {
          background: #FF9800;
          margin: 2px;
          display: inline-block;
          padding: 5px;
          color: #fff;
        }
        li.active {
          background: #8BC34A;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Функцию задать как ф-ю, а не closure, и вызывать и сразу, и через `setTimeout()`

Comment: это вы хорошо сказали... только к сожалению мало что понятно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы код был более читаемым, предлагаю функции объявлять как переменные. Для ритма анимации все интервалы лучше считать в какой-то общей мере –  «шагах».

```js
var blinking = false
  ,$w = $(window)
  ,$items = $("ul li")
  ,step = 400
;

function reset() {
  $items.removeClass("active");
  setTimeout( go, step);
}

function go() {
  $items.each( function(i, el) {
      setTimeout( function(){ $(el).addClass("active")}, i * step);
  });
  setTimeout( reset, $items.length * step);
}

function onScroll() {  
  if( blinking || $w.scrollTop() <= 300) return;
  blinking = true;
  go();
}

$(window).on('scroll', onScroll);
```

```css
body{height:2800px}ul{display:block;position:fixed}li{background:#FF9800;margin:2px;display:inline-block;padding:5px;color:#fff}li.active{background:#8BC34A}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

А ещё, если подумать глубокой лунной ночью, вся анимация по кругу идёт и ложится на сетку шагов. Значит, можно просто отщёлкивать эти шаги, инкрементируя целый счётчик, и, в зависимости от остатка деления на длину цикла, выполнять то или иное действие:

- шаги 0..L-1 это включения item'ов,
- L-й – гасим все.

```js
var blinking = false
  ,$w = $(window)
  ,$items = $("ul li")
  ,L = $items.length
  ,stepDelay = 400
  ,step = 0
;

function tick() {
  if( step < L) $($items[step]).addClass("active");
  else if( step === L) $items.removeClass("active");
  step++;
  if( step > L) step = 0;
}

function go() {
  window.setInterval( tick, stepDelay);
}

function onScroll() {  
  if( blinking || $w.scrollTop() <= 300) return;
  blinking = true;
  go();
}

$(window).on('scroll', onScroll);
```

```css
body{height:2800px}ul{display:block;position:fixed}li{background:#FF9800;margin:2px;display:inline-block;padding:5px;color:#fff}li.active{background:#8BC34A}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я в таких случаях использую `setTimeout`, к примеру:

```
(function add() {
  ...
  setTimeout(add, 6400);
})();
```

Ну или в Вашем случае, без вызова:

```
function add() {
  ...
  setTimeout(add, 6400);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstTime = true;
function addFunc(){
    $("ul li").each(function(i, el) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(el).addClass("active");
      }, 0 + (i * 800));
    })
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("ul li").removeClass("active");
    }, 5600)
}

function add() {
  if(!firstTime) setInterval(addFunc, 6400);
    else { firstTime=false; addFunc(); }
}
```

Comment: это внутри моей add вставлять я так понял?

Comment: так и не понял, как это будет работать с моим примером...

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов
Может не самый красивый способ, но как вариант. Выносим код в другую функцию и в add его выполняем с таймером только если значение переменной firstTime равен false. Этим заменить всю Вашу функцию add.
Вот еще там,думаю, можно: http://www.sitepoint.com/create-one-time-events-javascript/